# Is it possible to write right outer join where it would always be empty left part?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Here is an example what I want.

We have 2 tables - users and departments

```
users:
id name  d_id
1  Alice 1
2  Bob   1

departments:
id name
1  Sales
2  Support
```

Next, I write usual right join:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, d.name AS d_name
FROM users u
RIGHT OUTER JOIN departments d ON u.d_id = d.id
```

It returns:

```
id      name        d_name
--      --------    ---------
1       Alice       Sales
2       Bob         Sales
NULL    NULL        Support
```

Is it possible to write query, that returns next result?

```
id      name        d_name
--      --------    ---------
1       Alice       Sales
2       Bob         Sales
NULL    NULL        Sales
NULL    NULL        Support
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would appear to want `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, d.name AS d_name
FROM users u JOIN
     departments d
     ON u.d_id = d.id
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, NULL, d.name
FROM departments d
ORDER BY id NULLS LAST;
```

There is no need for an outer join for the first subquery.

Comment: Though you answered exactly my question (and I'm going to accept it after timeout) - could you answer more questions? 1) Is it possible to order result of query (with union), eg by `d.id`? Apply limit/offset? 2) What about performance? I expect about 10k-100k rows in the left table and 1k-10k rows in the right.

Comment: @MikDiet: `order by 1 nulls last`

Answer (score 3):

Use a UNION to add departments that haven't been listed yet:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, d.name AS d_name
FROM users u
RIGHT OUTER JOIN departments d ON u.d_id = d.id

UNION

SELECT NULL, NULL, d.name
FROM departments
```

Comment: Gordon Linoff's solution using an `INNER JOIN` and `UNION ALL` will likely perform better than the `RIGHT JOIN` and `UNION` offered in this answer. Unless you have a specific need, use Gordon Linoff's answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select 
        T.id,
        T.name,
        CASE WHEN T.d_name IS NULL THEN d.name ELSE T.d_name END d_name 
from (
SELECT 
        u.id, 
        u.name, 
        d.name AS d_name,
        did
FROM Users u
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN Departments d 
ON u.did = d.id )T
    FULL OUTER JOIN  Departments d
ON T.did <> d.id
```

Comment: @mikDiet in this way also we can achieve